# why correct answer = 0 when i run that generateQA function , they come from redux both x,y and correctanswer react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

```
class App extends Component {
```

> here i have tried to multiply the things that i got from store, correct answer is from store too

```
   generateQA = () => {
    this.setState({ correctAnswer: this.props.x*this.props.y})
    
  }
```

> here i imported the state from store

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      x: state.x,
      y: state.y,
      correctAnswer: state.correctAnswer
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = () => {
    return {
      generateX, 
      generateY,
      generateEmptyAnswer
    }
  }
 


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps())(App);
```

Comment: Is there a state named correctAnswer which is local to the component where generateQA is used ? You said correctAnswer is global in redux store but there you are trying to set a local state. Kinda confusing.

Comment: I was trying like this beause i did not found an option to add it another way...was thinking it might work... what I want is that after executing the function generateQA to multiply the 2 golbal states x and y and add it to a third global state called correctAnswer...  generateQA = () => {

   ({correctAnswer: x*y})
    
  }   I am not sure I can do this with redux...